# Htaccess Regex problem with redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess

When I use this in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If you go to site.com without www it redirects to www.site.com/.php instead of www.site.com.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by adding $1 to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1  [R=301,L]

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's browser's cache from your old `.htaccess`? Try to empty the cache, or use other browser (or maybe Priavte Browsing).

Comment: I've done that I think it has something to do with this              RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Answer (score 1):

I think at the root SCRIPT_FILENAME would be "/", which would not be considered a valid file and trip the !-f causing the rule to be applied.

Since the / is a character caught by the regex it will rewrite it to www.site.com/.php

Comment: I think that this would accomplish what you're looking for?
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "last" to rule by adding ",L":

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/ [R=301,L]
```